# How can I study the convergence of a complex series at the boundary?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I've been given the following series complex series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}z^n $$
for $z\in\mathbb{C}$. It is easy to see( by the ratio test) that the series converges when $|z|< 1$ and diverges when $|z|>1$. I need to see where at the boundary this series converges and where it diverges.

The nth term goes to $0$ when $|z|=1$, which doesn't give information to us. If $|z|=1$, then there exists a $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ such that $z= e^{i\theta}$. So, the series has real part: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\cos(n\theta) $$
and imaginary part:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sin(n\theta) $$
But these are alternating series to which the Leibnitz criterion cannot be applied ( the generating sequence isn't decreasing, nor positive). I don't really know how to proceed from here. Can you help me? Also tell if you know an easier way of checking this.

Comment: Are you comfortable dealing with the series that has no $(-1)^n$? If so notice that $(-1)^n=e^{i\pi n}$ so it can be asborbed in the exponential by the change of variable $\theta$ goes into $\theta + \pi$ where $z=re^{i\theta}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z=-1$, then the series diverges, since it is just the harmonic series. Otherwise, it converges, by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test). There is no need to conider the real part and the imaginary part separately.

Comment: Can you specify it a little bit? I don't see how to apply that test. Which part has partial sums bounded and which part is decreasing to 0 ?

Comment: $$\lvert-z+z^2-z^3+z^4-\cdots\pm z^n\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{-z\mp z^{n+1}}{1+z}\right\rvert\leqslant\frac2{\lvert1+z\rvert}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This series can be summed in a closed form. We have
$$\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n\ge0}z^n.$$
Then
$$\int\frac{1}{1-z}dz=-\log(1-z)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{z^{n}}{n}.$$
So your series is just $-\log(1+z)$.